# php include doesn't work even inside the same folder

Tags: php, include

reg.php is in `members` folder

```
<?php include "members/reg.php";?>  // doesn't work
<?php include ("members/reg.php");?>  // doesn't work
```

Then I replace `reg.php` in the same folder as the current file

```
<?php include "reg.php";?>  //doesn't work.
```

Comment: try by adding some space-> <?php include "reg.php"; ?> although not very sure but for clarity

Comment: what error it is giving try by turning error reporting on may be permissions problem

Comment: Have u checked with file permission (if you are using Linux)

Comment: What is the include path? http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php

Comment: <?php
 include("members/reg.php"); 
?>
try giving this.

Comment: Always [use `E_ALL`](http://php.net/errorfunc.constants) during development.

Comment: Hm, this space before `?>` works. But it's a bit strange, isnt it ? Anyway, solved, thanks a lot to everyone.

Comment: @Alegro, huh?!?! That should not cause it to not work as PHP ignores whitespace as far as I am aware.

Comment: @cryptic, yes I know. But I didn't change anything except this space. Mybe `swapnesh` could explain, It's his solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', true );

include './members/reg.php';
```

Possibly the include worked but caused a silenced error.

Answer (score 2):

With:

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

you can define the root of your project (which is the one the file you put it in) and then call:

```
include ROOT."members/reg.php";
```

Comment: The thing is if 'member/reg.php' is a subfolder and file within the current working directory it should work. As PHP will check for includes in the include_path, but also within the current directory.

Comment: @cryptic, with this method it will always work because it always uses absolute paths.

Comment: I agree it will work, but it does not answer the problem as to why it currently does not work when it *should* work. Providing an alternate way to do something does not solve the current dilemma. But apparently OP figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your main web page file has extension .php instead of .htm. If it does not have .php extension, then include will simply not work. You won't get an error or a warning. It just won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
<?php include("../members/reg.php") ?>
```

The 2 points tell the include to go to the previous folder, and from there enter the 'members' folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to change / because is diferent in windows and linux. You can use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead.

```
include_once "Model".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."MyFile.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. It worked when I removed the "?>" in the file that is included.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

At the beginning, before you set `reg.php` to your current folder, you should try this:

```
<?php include('../members/reg.php') ?>
```

If you do this

```
<?php include('members/reg.php') ?>
```

your program is going to think that there is a folder inside your current folder named `members`, which there isn't. The 2 dots tell you to go a folder backwards.