# PHP include tag not displaying file data

Tags: php, html, file, include

So I have a welcome page here that includes a php include tag.

welcome.php

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title> Web Application</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/welcome_stylesheet.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="welcome.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="welcome">
        <div id="container">
            <p id="welcome_page_h1">Welcome</p>
                <div id="select_container">
                    <?php include("stuff.php"); ?>
                </div>
        </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

And here's thee php file I am trying to include/display.

stuff.php:

```
<p> Well how y'all doin? </p>
<p> Well how y'all doin? </p>
<p> Well how y'all doin? </p>
<p> Well how y'all doin? </p>
```

I feel like all my ducks are in order here, but nothing shows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try without the parenthesis.

```
<?php include "stuff.php"; ?>
```

Comment: @ClayBanks, in that case, hoping both these files are in the same directory.

Comment: They are indeed in the same directory. Everything is structured fine

Answer (score 0):

I have a page called **index.php** and inside that page I use the following code...

```
<?php include 'header.html'; ?>
```

**header.html** is in the same directory as **index.php**

Comment: Very strange, none of these seem to be working. I've done this before and never had this problem

Comment: It could be your environment or permission issues. Are PHP files running at all?

Comment: Yes my welcome.php page runs fine, it's the include file that just won't show. I am on my company computer and there are various permission guards, securities, etc. But I feel like it wouldn't affect something like this. I had even tried JSTL's include, but to no avail :(

Comment: two things I would suggest are, using this site [c9 - cloud nine](https://c9.io) for an alternate environment to test in. Also take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051449/php-include-doesnt-work-even-inside-the-same-folder) to enable silenced errors

Answer (score 0):

If you change the file extension of the file you want to include to be something OTHER than .php, it will work.

Ie:
welcome.php

```
//   . . . 
 <div id="select_container">
      <?php include("stuff.txt"); ?>
 </div>
```

stuff.txt

```
<p> Well how y'all doin? </p>
<p> Well how y'all doin? </p>
<p> Well how y'all doin? </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check spelling and your **index.php** in the same dir with **welcome.php**

if all it's ok you can check it use this simple code :

```
<?php
    echo ((include "index.php") == "OK") ? "OK" : "FAILED";
?>
```

Or use this code

```
<?php
function get_file_content($filename) {
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        ob_start();
        include $filename;
        return ob_get_clean();
    } else {
        ob_clean();
        trigger_error("The file {$filename} was not found");
    }
}

echo get_file_content("index.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and realized that it was a line of PHP code that I forgot to end with a semi-colon.

How I checked was to slowly delete chunks of code from the included file that I think might affect the code and run until I can narrow the source.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after hours of troubleshooting i found out that i never installed php -_-  fixed the issue for me.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php
```